# Redirect http to https haproxy use ssl passthrough

Tags: ssl, tcp, haproxy

here is my configuration

**frontend www-http**

```
   bind *:80

option tcplog

  default_backend www-backend

mode tcp
```

**frontend www-https**

```
   bind *:443

   default_backend www-backend

option tcplog

mode tcp
```

**backend www-backend**

mode tcp

```
   server web1 192.168.1.191:443 check

   server web2 192.168.1.192:443 check backup
```

I want to when users types mysite.com >> https://mysites.com

I used redirect scheme https if `!{ ssl_fc }` on frontend as backend, but it cant reach my goal.

Comment: I think you are asking same question than in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227544/haproxy-redirecting-http-to-https-ssl

Comment: I did try, but it does not work... it just used for ssl termination.

Comment: Even tested this variant?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19677632/4886927

Comment: yes, but i need redirect all trafic. :)

Answer (score 3):

It may be late, but the following works:

```
frontend LB
    bind :80 v4v6
    mode http
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

frontend LBS
    bind :443 v4v6
    option tcplog
    mode tcp
    default_backend LBB

backend LBB
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server srv1 server1.example.com:443 check
    server srv2 server2.example.com:443 check backup
```